# TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, discord.py

Estoy haciendo un *bot* en *python*, me pide que añada en un sitio un argumento por alguna extraña razón, así que yo lo hago pero siempre que ejecuto mi código aparece esto:

```python
# bot.py
import os

import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.environ['TOKEN']

client = discord.Client(1)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')

client.run(TOKEN)
```

> TypeError: **init**() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: Seguro que el error te indicó la línea. ¿Cual línea sería?

Comment: Le estas pasando un 1 a discord.Client.  Y discord.Client no acepta ningun argumento posicional. En resumen, quita ese 1. Realmente no se que intencion tenias al agregarlo.